# I am trying to plot numeric values against an ordered list of alphabetical values

Tags: r, plot, categorical-data

The default settings in R create a the plot shown. I need the x axis to be ordered `AAA, AA, A+, A, B, C, D, E, F, G, HR`. The alphabetical values are credit ratings (variable credrating) and numeric values is the cdr variable.

The code I have is:

```
plot(credrating, cdr)
```

[image]

Comment: you need to use `credrating = factor(credrating, levels=c('AAA','AA', etc.))`.  See `?factor` for more info.

Comment: @C8H10N4O2 is correct. Next time, however, be sure to include a reproducible example. See some [good guidelines here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)